# Updating string based on dictionary key value in python where key is partial string

Tags: python, sql, string, dictionary, key

I have a string that I want to update with values based on specific keys. My challenge is that that one of the values in my dictionary is partially a string value

```
parameters = {"$1":"'name'", 
              "$2":"hierarchy LIKE '%|user_name|%'"}
```

String that I'd like to replace $1 and $2 with the values is:

```
query = """
  SELECT
    $1 AS org,
   FROM
     table
   WHERE
     input ='Active'
     AND $2
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
"""
```

I then run it through the below code:

```
for key in parameters.keys():
    query = query.replace(key, parameters[key])
```

It works fine for replacing $1 with 'name' but it does not replace $2 appropriately. We end up getting:

`print(query)`

output:

```
"""
  SELECT
    'name' AS org,
   FROM
     table
   WHERE
     input ='Active'
     AND hierarchy
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
"""
```

The issue is when replacing $2, it leaves out the full string. Any tips?

Comment: Can you change a little bit the query and put brackets to wrap the `$1` ?

Comment: Actually, your loop works for me Which version on Python are you using?

Comment: So odd, I'm using Python 3. it's dropping off the " LIKE '%|user_name|%'" part of the value for some reason for me

Comment: What do you mean by putting brackets around $1? That part is actually WAI I think

Comment: I mean you could write ` SELECT {$1} AS org, FROM table WHERE input ='Active' AND {$2} GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` and then `query.format(**parameters)`. Does it work better?

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. I'm trying to think of it more as updating strings, less as a sql problem.

Comment: It produces the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
print(re.sub('\$\d+', lambda x:parameters[x.group()], query))
```

Output

```
SELECT
  'name' AS org,
FROM
  table
WHERE
  input ='Active'
  AND hierarchy LIKE '%|user_name|%'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parameters = {
    "$1": "'name'", 
    "$2": "hierarchy LIKE '%|user_name|%'",
}
```

`str.replace`

```
query = """
  SELECT
    $1 AS org,
   FROM
     table
   WHERE
     input ='Active'
     AND $2
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
"""

for key, value in parameters.items():
    query = query.replace(key, value)
```

The old way: `str % (params)`

```
query = """
  SELECT
    %s AS org,
   FROM
     table
   WHERE
     input ='Active'
     AND %s
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
""" % (parameters['$1'], parameters['$2'])
```

Better: `str.format`

```
query = """
  SELECT
   {$1} AS org,
   FROM
     table
   WHERE
     input ='Active'
     AND {$2}
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
""".format(**parameters)
```

New way: `f'string'`

```
query = f"""
  SELECT
   {parameters['$1']} AS org,
   FROM
     table
   WHERE
     input ='Active'
     AND {parameters['$2']}
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
"""
```

Tip: Do not use bare string formatting when working with SQL. Pay a lot of attention for these parts of code since SQL injections are widely known vulnerabilities.

Tip: Check if your python version is outdated. (New stable version: 3.9), but don't be rash with upgrading it anyways